# CSS classnames are being interpreted in a different order in production/development

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, create-react-app

I'm using create-react-app v2.

I have a component with several classnames: "x15 x14 login-form__field". In the HTML they are the same order in both environments.

In the production build, '.x14' appears in a higher priority than 'login-form__field'. They are reversed (and correct) in development. Any ideas? I know webpack does some hoisting and post-processing, but not sure why this would affect it.

[image: Dev & Prod class order]

[image: Development][image: Production]

Cheers

**-- Update --**

I've just noticed that the custom class is being loaded in as an inline style, which is why it gets priority. I assume webpack is doing this. Is there anyway we can tell webpack/CRA to load styles as stylesheets - not inline. Otherwise it means the styles are not representative of production.

**-- Second Update --**

Create-react-app uses 'styleLoader' for inline-styles in dev for hot reloading and generates CSS for production only. This makes sense.

Comment: Interesting. Have you ejected, or is it the default Webpack config you are using? Sounds like a good candidate for a bug report.

Comment: I haven't ejected. Using default config that is provided by CRA. See my update for why I think this is happening - no idea how to rectify though.

Comment: I have similar issue, development styles not representing what production is going to have. I see in development everything is styles, but for production it is css file. How to resolve this. I am using react-script version 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create-react-app uses 'styleLoader' for inline-styles in dev for hot reloading and generates CSS for production only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using css modules in your project and if by chance you are using `composes` in your classes then this can happen. If you are using composes in one class to inherit properties from another class in different file then ordering does not hold good for the purpose.